# Which status code should be returned: 200 or 4xx?

Tags: rest, http

I've read different opinions and I don't quite understand which one is correct. Consider situation where client have to send POST request to server for payment.Which status code should server return if client doesn't have enough balance :   4xx or 200(with error message in response) and why ?

Comment: Really, it's up to you -- whatever makes sense to your client.  402 can certainly be used for "payment required", or you can consider it a normal response with an error code in the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP status codes are metadata of the [transfer-of-documents-over-a-network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s) domain.  Domain information (ex: insufficient balance) belongs in the message payload.

Sending a response that announces success in the HTTP domain (200) with a response that describes a failure in the business domain (insufficient funds) is  a perfectly normal thing to do.

A case where it matters: when there can be previously cached responses for the same resource -- HTTP compliant caches invalidate previously cached responses for the same resource if an unsafe request (like POST) returns a non-error status code.  See [RFC 9111](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html#name-invalidating-stored-respons).

So the "right" answer is to return a 200 (usually) with a message body that describes the problem, and affordances to help the client resolve the issue (for example, links to the documents that explain how to put more money in the account).

The reason that we care is to enable the *general purpose* components participating in the conversation (browsers, caches, etc) to understand what is happening at the transfer of documents level so that they can do intelligent things (like cache invalidation).

---

Is doing it the right way *important*?  That depends a lot on whether you are expecting general purpose components to do useful things.

For example, if this resource doesn't support GET/HEAD requests, then there aren't likely to be a lot of cached responses lying about, so the benefits of cache-invalidation would be negligible.

And, let's face it: there are a lot of API around that mix domain concerns into their HTTP status codes; you can do it "wrong" and still be successful.

Answer (score 1):

If the intention of the request is to make a payment, and the payment fails for any reason, that's an error and therefore a 4xx code (probably 409).

If you make a request, and you receive a 200. The assumption is that the request succeeded. Since the goal was to make a payment and this didn't happen, returning a 200 status code would give a user the false impression it was successful.